# Is it illegal to buy stocks at a low price during a flash crash using a low GTC order?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, limit-order

We've seen several flash crashes in the past few years, and I suspect algorithms are some of what's behind these ([see this as an example](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2015-05-06/swiss-stock-market-collapses-instantaneously-5th-anniversary-flash-crash)).  In a short period of time, an exchange will suddenly see tons of sells and fall dramatically, only to self-correct.

Using an example of the SPY, would it be legal to put in a Good-Til-Cancelled order for $100 a share and make a profit on the flash crash, if it occurs?  Note that the assumption here is that it crashes in a short period of time (within a day), not over time (so the order can be re-arranged if the market declines over a period of time).

Comment: You are basically asking if it is illegal to attempt a trade during a flash crash. What law would you imagine being broken?

Comment: They seem to be coming down hard on the people behind this; I'd wonder if it would raise flags about the person being behind it.  Technically, it's a matter of seeing the market as being influenced by computers that can go nuts sometimes.  Just verifying is all!

Comment: Often times flash crash trades are cancelled, in some markets affected.

Comment: The market maker for those securities would suspend trading after a certain threshold is exceeded.  You can put in your order, but the chances of it being executed are very slim.

Comment: @user541852587 you are conflating several issues. Only people profiting from spoofing are being charged with anything so far. Has nothing to do with actual flash crashes or liquidity disruptions

Comment: Why are you asking only about stocks and only about crashes?  There have been *far* more examples of flash moves in non-equity markets over the past 5 years than in equity markets, and many of them have been flash spikes rather than flash crashes. Are you trying to learn more about the market mechanics that go into a flash move? Or are you just interested in talking about legalities (in which case your question is off-topic for this site)?

Comment: You put in an order for $100, but what was the price before the crash and after the crash? What happens if you put your order for $100 and the price continues to go down? Or are you shorting the stock? A bit hard to understand what you are actually asking here!

Comment: Be careful; if a stock loses most of its value over a few minutes, that might be a blip caused by a software bug, or maybe everyone just found out they'd been cooking the books for the last few years or something, and it's not coming back up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A person executing a single order during a flash crash would not be high on the suspect list for the cause of the crash, so no, I wouldn't worry about it at all. There is nothing wrong with taking advantage of whipsawing prices as long as you didnt cause them.

Comment: didn't cause them and didn't know they're going to be caused, you mean

Comment: @littleadv What, is it illegal not to tell the company that their algorithm was going to cause it?

Comment: @CBauer No but it is illegal to have knowledge of it before hand and act on that knowledge. Something something fraud something.

Comment: @corsiKa but not for index futures. or any market that is not stock market, in the united states

Comment: This answer does not seem to actually address the question.  The OP does not seem to be concerned with being blamed for causing the crash, but rather with whether there is some prohibition about participating in the market during the event.  To say `there is nothing wrong with taking advantage` would not be a correct statement if you violated some regulation in order to do so (such as insider trading, violating RegNMS, etc.).

Comment: @dg99 but again even here, the OP asked about the SPY which is an S&P500 ETF and gave an example of a flash crash in the Swiss index, these crashes are caused in the futures market which would not be subject to insider trading prohibitions. I should vote to close this question